# Expo not starting

Tags: javascript, react-native

Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest failed, reason: write EPROTO 00DE56DE01000000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/extensions.c:922:

FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest failed, reason: write EPROTO 00DE56DE01000000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/extensions.c:922:

```
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/\user/Desktop/react_native_test/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1505:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I am trying to run a project, which was successful yesterday with the command npx expo start after that I was again trying to run the project but encountering the above error and tried different commands like npm start, expo start, npx expo start, npm start --offline like suggested in previous questions regarding the same, but I am still getting the above error for all the commands used, what should I be doing to eliminate this issue.